# Be at / in the / in hospital

Tags: prepositions, definite-article, zero-article

I have seen the difference between 'go to hospital' and 'go to the hospital'. Now what is the diffrence of the following three sentences

> Be at hospital.
>
> Be in hospital.
>
> Be in the hospital.

Comment: The difference between "be in hospital" and "be in the hospital" is the same as in example you provided (patient/not patient). "Be at hospital"  looks incorrect to me, though "be at the hospital" can be used when referring to a person not being a patient.

Comment: Related: [Is there a reason the British omit the article when they “go to hospital”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/19604/47827).

Comment: Your question seems to be more about articles, which is answered here on the site. http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44588/usage-of-articles-before-the-noun-hospital

Answer (score 0):

Americans use *the*, Brits do not.