# Using "at a jail" vs. "in a jail"

Tags: prepositions

We often use "at" for the mentioning of a precise location like; He is present at school. But why not say he is imprisoned at a jail instead use he is in a jail.

Comment: Similarly We also say she is being operated in Saidu Sharif hospital but not at SS hospital. So what about this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of articles before the noun 'hospital'](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44588/usage-of-articles-before-the-noun-hospital)

Comment: @AlanCarmack A duplicate for the comment maybe, but not the question, due to the BrE distinction using "hospital".

Comment: "Just visiting" versus "In Jail" http://monopoly.wikia.com/wiki/Jail

Comment: Which of these people is "in jail," and which is merely "at a jail"? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nQkiJT2MR4w

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I came here just to make the Monopoly reference.

Answer (score 28):

If you are at the jail building, then you can say:

> I am **at** the jail.

or "detention facility" or such.

But if you were arrested and locked up, then you would say:

> > I am **in** jail.

because you are in the jail cell, cell block and such.

Comment: Note:  The former describes one's location, while the latter (by omitting the article) describes the state of being incarcerated.

Comment: Just to emphasize - there is a difference between `I am *in* jail` and `I am *in a* jail`

Comment: @rhughes Which is? I would only use "I am *in a* jail" in the form of "I am in a jail *cell*".

Comment: @user3169 - rhughes is correct as I would suggest that you could use `in a jail` if you qualify _which_ jail, i.e. `I am in a jail in Mexico`

Comment: In other words: http://imgur.com/JcAwtqi

Comment: @user3169 The difference is that "in a jail" is not an idiomatic way of saying "imprisoned," while "in jail" is.

Comment: @KyleStrand True, but "in a jail" really needs additional context, otherwise I would use the idiomatic phrase. The original question did not (a good example why sufficient content in questions is important).

Comment: @user3169 It sounds like you're agreeing with rhughes' comment, then, but your original comment didn't make that clear.

Comment: @Greenonline But "I am in a jail in Mexico" still only means "I am located within a jail in Mexico", whereas "I am in jail in Mexico" means "I am imprisoned in Mexico".

Answer (score 14):

When referring to something like **jail** or **school**, **at** tends to refer to being at the physical location, and (unless the listener is aware of additional information) generally is preceded or succeeded by some verb phrase stating what the subject is doing at that location.  For example, you might say, *Joe works at the jail* or *Joe is serving time at the county jail*.  In both cases, since **at** does not make it apparent what Joe is doing, additional information is required.  Now, if the listener knows that Joe is a law enforcement officer or a habitual troublemaker, one could simply say *Joe is at the county jail* and the listener would be able to infer what Joe was doing there.

**School** is similar.  Stating that Julie is *at the school* has different implications depending on what is already known about Julie.  If the listener knows Julie as a school-aged child, then the listener would infer that Julie is *at school attending classes.*  If the listener knows Julie as a teacher, then the listener would infer that Julie is *at school teaching classes*.

**In** on the other hand implies that, not only is the subject at a physical place, but is also engaged in the primary activity that occurs at that place.  Stating that *Joe is in jail* implies that Joe is incarcerated at the jail (regardless of what the listener knows about Joe) since incarceration is the primary activity that occurs at a jail.  Stating *Julie is in school* implies that Julie is attending classes at a school since attending class is the primary thing one does at a school.

**Hospitals** are a similar case as well.  Stating that *Gerald is at the hospital* would imply different things depending on what the listener knows about Gerald (is Gerald a nurse, or an elderly man, or an ambulance driver?).  Stating that *Gerald is in the hospital* immediately implies that Gerald is hospitalized for the purposes of receiving care for an injury on illness.

In summary, **at** is somewhat more ambiguous as it specifies where the subject is, but leaves what the subject is doing up to inference.  **In** is less ambiguous as it implies that the subject as at a location and is engaged in the primary thing that occurs at the location.  **In** is short for stating that *Joe is incarcerated at the jail* or *Julie is in school taking classes.*

Answer (score 3):

(I would like to start with general differences between *in* and *at* because in some parts of my answer I'm going to bring them up.)

We use *at* when we're talking about ***an address, a public place or building*** (a bus stop, the Post Office, the library etc.) and *cases in which the location is irrelevant* but ***what we do*** there is what is important (school, the dentist, dance class etc).

> My mother is staying at 66 Argyle Street.
>
> We study different subjects at school.

Use *in* to describe the physical location of something as part of a larger thing or place.

> Liam has a flat in Paris.

About *jail*, it can be a countable or uncountable noun. As an *uncountable noun* we use it idiomatically in such phrases:

> He **was** arrested and **sent/sentenced to jail**.
>
> He **went to jail** for his crimes.
>
> He just got **out of jail** a few weeks ago.
>
> He was kept **in jail** overnight (*in jail* idiomatically means locked up as prisoners)

As a *countable noun* we use it with an article like *the* as in

> He was locked up in the county jail.

We say ***at the jail*** idiomatically when you want to refer to jail as a general location where something happens as in

> I visit her at the jail every Saturday.

We use ***at a jail*** when we talk about *one jail that we don't want to be specific about it* as in

> Nineteen prisoners have been killed in the second riot in less than a week at a jail in Nebraska.

In both cases though there is a relevance between the place and an event, then we use *at*.

***In the jail*** can be used **in this sense**, too, although it's not really idiomatic. I think here it's mostly used when we want to emphasise on the physical location as in

> Playing sports professionally in the jail is something I don't think would work!

***In the jail*** is *mostly* used when you want to refer to *being there as a prisoner* as in

> He was arrested for drunkenness and spent a night in the city jail.

To put it in a nutshell, ***in jail*** and ***in the (usually the name) jail*** is used when you're locked up there.

***At a/the jail*** refers to the general location and usually there is the implication of something happening there.

Answer (score 1):

> But why not say he is imprisoned at a jail instead use he is in a jail.

Fundamentally, there is not a problem with saying "He is imprisoned at a jail." - it is perfectly understandable.

That said, there is a nuance to stating it this way - it is *redundant*. Except in a hyperbolic sense, one would not be imprisoned at a school, for example. The state of being *imprisoned* implies *at a jail* without it being necessary to state this explicitly.