# go to university or go to the university

Tags: phrase-usage, articles, verbs, collocations

I'm a bit confused. I know that "go to university" is a collocation which means going to attend university. What if I want to say that I'm heading to, walking to, the university. Can I say "I'm going to the university tomorrow morning"?

Comment: Sure. Leaving out the article merely means you have matriculated, i.e., that you are enrolled there. Note that there are differences between BrE and AmE in this. Cf. BrE "in hospital" vs. AmE "in *the* hospital," etc.

Comment: Could you please explain? I don't get it.

Comment: In BrE (British English) one says "I go to university" meaning one attends classes for credit at an institute of higher learning; one would say "I'm going to the university" meaning one intends to physically go to the campus. (In AmE (American English) one says "I go to college" even if the institution is a university.)

Comment: So if I say, in AmE, "I'm going to the college" would it mean that I'm physically going there? sorry still confused. I got the first part about the "go to university" and "go to the university".

Comment: Yes. "I'm going to the college" would mean you're physically going there.

Comment: Related to and probably a duplicate of [Usage of articles before the noun 'hospital'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44588/usage-of-articles-before-the-noun-hospital)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use **the**, if you go there not as a student.
There is great explanation in Raymond Murphy's "English grammar in use" (unit 74 A, B):

> Compare **school** and **the school**:
>
> - Ellie is ten years old. Every day she goes **to school**. She's **at school**
>     now. **School** starts at 9 and finished at 3.
>
> We say a child goes **to school** or is **at school** (as a student). We are
>   not thinking of a specific school. We are thinking of school as a
>   general idea - children learning in a classroom.
>
> - Today Elle's mother wants to speak to her daughter's teacher. So she
>     has gone to **the school** to see her. She's at **the school** now.
>
> Ellie's mother is not a student. She is not 'at school'. She doesn't
>   'go to school'. If she wants to see Ellie's teacher, she goes to **the
>   school** (=Ellie's school, a specific building).
>
> We use **prison** (or **jail**), **hospital**, **university**, **college** and 
>   **church** in a similar way. We don't use **the** when we are thinking of the 
>   general idea of these places and what they are used for.
>
> Compare:
>
> - Ken's brother is **in prison** for robbery. (He is a prisoner. We are not thinking of a specific prison)
> - Ken went to **the prison** to visit his brother. (He went as a visitor, not as a prisoner.)
>
> ---
>
> - Joe had an accident last week. He was taken **to hospital**. He's still **in hospital** now. (as a patient)
> - Jane has gone to **the hospital** to visit Joe. She's at **the hospital** now. (as a visitor, not as a patient)
>
> ---
>
> - When I leave school, I plan to go **to university**/go **to collage** (as a student)
> - I went to **the university** to meet Professor Thomas (as a visitor, not as a student).
>
> ---
>
> - Sally's father goes **to church** every Sunday (to take part in a religious
>     service)
> - Some workmen went **to the church** to repair the roof. (not for
>     a religious service)

Comment: What if the speaker is the professor himself to mean he went there to teach his class. He is not a student, yet he's there to teach. In this case, he went to university or he went to the university to teach his class?

Comment: In AmE, to the hospital,regardless. To hospital is really more British.

Answer (score 0):

When we say "**the professor went to the university to teach**" we mean that he went to the university--as a building--and his *purpose* was to teach, in other words, when he (professor) goes *to the* university has a purpose as well as he is involved in the building per se, and obviuosly as a member. On the contrary, when we say "**he went to university**" we mean that he went there as probably a professor of that institution and evindently to teach.