# When to use the definite article

Tags: definite-article

A friend has a lot of trouble with when to use 'the'. E.g. he will say: 'I'm going to gym', or 'I'm going to city'. Both of these examples need the definite article.  However, it is fine to say 'I'm going to school' or 'I'm going to Woolies'. How can I explain this to my class? Is there a rule? Is there an already developed worksheet??!

Comment: This question is way too broad to write a reasonably comprehensive answer to. Woolies, if I am not mistaken, is an Aussie grocery chain? In that case, it is a proper noun and should be treated the same way as Sydney or Australia. People don't normally say "I am going to the Australia*" (unless the context demands specification/designation). "I am going to school" is a whole different can of worms.

Comment: It's fine to say "I'm going to school" if you are attending school as a student. If you were going there to speak to your child's teacher, or to attend a concert, you would say "I'm going to the school".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [go to university or go to the university](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/140982/go-to-university-or-go-to-the-university)